# Copy and pasting in Photoshop leaves transparent edge on image

Tags: copy, photoshop, transparent, paste

I'm making cuts of an image to use in various parts of my website; The header, the footer, etc. When I copy and paste to a new layer, it leaves a "feathered" edge. even though I have this set to zero. There is a 1 pixel margin around all of the copy and pasted images, that, when assembled as a web page using CSS, leaves little lines between all of the images. I was a professional graphic designer but I've been out of the game too long (2 whole years). God help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the source of the initial assets such as the header and footer, so I'm a little confused (some links might be nice), however it is worth checking a few things just to make sure. Hit M for the marquee and check thats feather amount. L for the lasso (long shot) and check that too, also check for any layer styles.

A nice little alternative, if you are exporting out individual assets,is go to File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files. This may save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Hopefully this may help...

Additionally how are you copying? Is it from inside Photsohop or are you placing the layers? Are you using the marquee tool?

Answer (score 0):

for try, don't use crop tool.. use select tool instead. select tool provides pixel level accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to feather, try turning off anti-aliasing in your selections. After you make a selection, in the select options toolbar uncheck 'Anti-alias'.

[image]

If this is set photoshop will try to average the edges of the selection with the surrounding pixels to make it 'blend' better. This is worse than useless if you're trying to make accurate, pixel-level selections.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop CC, after selecting with the marquee tool, right click to access the Feather option. Enter 0.1 and then copy and paste. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem. I'd cut and pasted and then dragged into a new image which created a new layer with the paste on. I then realised that the feathering was wrong. I changed the settings but forgot to change the active layer back to the background layer, so I was cutting and pasting the feathered cut I did originally. Facepalm.